# HTML5 button.formaction Attribute Not Working Outside of <form>

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

Why does the `button.formaction` attribute not work outside of a `<form>`?

This fails:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="a.jsp">a<button>
<button type="submit" formaction="b.jsp">b<button>
<button type="submit" formaction="c.jsp">c<button>
```

However, this works for me:

```
<form action="foo.jsp" method="post">
    <button type="submit" formaction="a.jsp">a<button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="b.jsp">b<button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="c.jsp">c<button>
</form>
```

But in my application it does not make sense for me to use a form since I never want to access `foo.jsp` and I do not have a default. Is there some way to make formaction work without using a dummy value or defaulting the form to `a.jsp`?

Comment: I dont know, but an attribute called `formaction` seems right just works inside a `form`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I guess what I am trying to understand is what was the reasoning for tying it to a form in the specification? Is it just to separate the presentation from the logic? Then why introduce formaction...?

Comment: Since you are doing a formaction, it will send the form data in the request. So you need a form to submit.

Comment: If what's bothering you is the dummy action attribute, just don't specify it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general `form` elements are used to send data to a server. It wraps around the elements which specifies the data, `input` or `button` elements, for instance. If you add a `name` and a `value` attribute to your button elements, you will send this *name-value-pair* to your server.

If you don’t need to send any (additional) data to your server, just use link elements and style them like buttons using CSS, if you want to:

```
<a href="a.jsp" class="btn">a</a>
<a href="b.jsp" class="btn">b</a>
<a href="c.jsp" class="btn">c</a>
```

**The `formaction` attribute**

With the `formaction` attribute you can specify multiple *submit URLs* for **one** form. Because the `action` attribute is no longer required for the `form` element you could define the *submit URL(s)* just in the `formaction` of a submit button. When the form is submitted, the browser first checks for a `formaction` attribute; if that isn’t present, it proceeds to look for an `action` attribute on the form element. So the *form action* is something like a fallback or default, it is not required:

```
<form method="post">    
    <input type="text" name="my-data" value="my data"/>

    <button type="submit" formaction="a.jsp">a</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="b.jsp">b</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="c.jsp">c</button>        
</form>
```

If you use the `form` **attribute** on the button to reference the associated form (*id* value) you could even place the button outside of the `form` element:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="my-data" value="my data"/>
</form>

<button type="submit" formaction="a.jsp" form="myForm">a</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="b.jsp" form="myForm">b</button>
<button type="submit" formaction="c.jsp" form="myForm">c</button>
```